# PyQt - Easily add a QWidget to all Views

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have the following

```
class MyView(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(QLabel('Hello World'))
        self.setLayout(layout)


class NavigationMenu(QWidget):
    pass
    # Renders a bar of full width and 15 px height
```

What is the easiest way to add the `NavigationMenu` to `MyView`?

In the future, I would have to also add the `NavigationMenu` to all other Views, so I am looking for something scalable from a typing and maintainability stand point.

I tried decorators (just `@NavigationMenuDecorator` on top of the class), but I either cannot bind them or they get initialized at parse time and error `QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget`.

I tried just adding it into MyView, but there is a lot of boilerplate

```
class MyWidget(Widget.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        layout = Widget.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(QLabel('Hello World'))

        topLayout = Widget.QVBoxLayout()
        topLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        topLayout.addWidget(NavigationMenu())
        topLayout.addLayout(layout)

        self.setLayout(topLayout)
```

Comment: Your last option isn't boiler plate if you inherit from `MyWidget`.

Comment: But then I have to have 1 extra class for each of my views, right? That would be boilerplate. I am not really sure how your solution would look like though.

Comment: If each of your classes inherit from `MyWidget` then they'll all get the nav menu for free.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Could you elaborate more in an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution is to use metaclass:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class NavigationMenu(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("NavigationMenu"))

class MetaNavigationMenu(type(QtWidgets.QWidget), type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kw):
        obj = super().__call__(*args, **kw)
        lay = obj.layout()
        if lay is not None:
            lay.addWidget(NavigationMenu())
        return obj

class View(QtWidgets.QWidget, metaclass=MetaNavigationMenu):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('Hello World'))
        self.setLayout(layout)

if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = View()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Update:**

With the following method you can inject the view and the additional arguments that the view requires:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class NavigationMenu(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, value, text="", parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel(text))
        print(value)

class MetaMenu(type(QtWidgets.QWidget), type):
    def __new__(cls, class_name, parents, attrs, **kwargs):
        cls._view = kwargs.pop('view', None)
        cls._args = kwargs.pop('args', tuple())
        cls._kwargs = kwargs.pop('kwargs', dict())
        return type.__new__(cls, class_name, parents, attrs)

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kw):
        obj = super().__call__(*args, **kw)
        layout = getattr(obj, 'layout', None)
        if callable(layout) and View is not None:
            layout().addWidget(cls._view(*cls._args, **cls._kwargs))
        return obj

class View(QtWidgets.QWidget, metaclass=MetaMenu, view=NavigationMenu, args=(10, ), kwargs={"text": "NavigationMenu"}):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('Hello World'))
        self.setLayout(layout)

if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = View()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I think that would work. But what if the NavigationMenu takes some parameters (Like for instance the "NavigationMenu" `QLabel`)? Inheritance would have the same issue.

Comment: timezone difference, went to bed, sorry. The solution works, it is what I am looking for. I learned A LOT about metaclasses from it. Thank you for not only taking the time to write it, but also for explaining it to me. However it is not easily readable for the beginners in our codebase. I ended up just extracting the boilerplate into a function and using composition instead.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but cannot accept it. Thank you though!

Comment: @AndreiCioara unfortunately I do not write the code thinking about the level that the OP has on the subject, in my case I write the best solution regarding the facility (it does not imply the facility to understand for all but its use) and scalability :-)

Answer (score 0):

The other solution here is amazing and I learned a lot about metaclasses. However, it is quite hard to read and adds unnecessary complexity. I settled for a composition-based approach, where I just extracted the boilerplate to a separate function.

The `add_navigation()` function wraps the old layout in a widget, creates a QVBoxLayout with the `NavigationMenu` and the old layout, and finally swaps the layouts.

```
def add_navigation(widget, title)
    main = QWidget()
    main.setLayout(widget.layout())

    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    layout.setSpacing(0)
    layout.addWidget(NavigationBar(title))
    layout.addWidget(main)

    widget.setLayout(layout)
```

We then have just a 1-liner of boilerplate and the code then becomes.

```
class MyView(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(QLabel('Hello World'))
        self.setLayout(layout)

        add_navigation(self, 'Navigation Title')


class NavigationMenu(QWidget):
    pass
    # Renders a bar of full width and 15 px height
```